# Set Due Date to 25th of current/next month

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013

I would like to be able to set a due date when a task is created to be the 25th of the current/next month (depending on the current day).  For example, if the form is submitted on 11/1, the due date would be 11/25.  If it were done on 11/25 it would need to be due on 12/26.

Comment: If it were done on 11/25 it would need to be due on 12/25? Or 12/26? Would one submitted on 11/29 be due 12/25? Also, are you looking for a calculated column or default value?

Comment: Hi Aron, due dates would always be the 25th, but never the same day. That's why something submitted on 11/25 would be due 12/25 (I'm not worried about the holiday; I assume that would be too difficult to factor in). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Building a calculated field like this should do the trick

```
=IF(DAY([Created])<25, CONCATENATE(MONTH([Created]),"/",25), CONCATENATE(MONTH([Created])+1,"/",25))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please forgive me, but I'm new to SD2013. Where would I want to add this string? Thanks!

Comment: You would need to create a new column of type "Calculated Column", then use this code as the calculation.